# FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR|Operation not valid for this user type when creating Oppt related to contact via PlatformEvent Triggered Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, integration, automation, developer

I have a flow that triggers by a trigger that publishes a platform event, in the flow I do some fields updates, and I create a task and an opportunity related to the targetId passed from event to flow.

Im having the following error for opportunity creation element;

FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR|Operation not valid for this user type

Note; Ive admin permissions, I logged in as Reps & managers who can create Opps...etc but the error is still there...any idea please how to fix this ?

#Flow  #Salesforce Developer  #Automation  #Integration

Comment: Does [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_trigger_config.htm) help?

Comment: who is the running user for the Platform Event-triggered flow? (see [Who is running my flow](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2022/your-guide-to-determining-the-flow-running-user-and-its-execution-context)).  This will determine your next diagnostic step